# How to set variable within Java class from within another class

Tags: java, object, getter-setter, setter

I'm trying to set up a simple set of classes in Java in such a way that a specific Trader class (see below) can 'talk' to other Robot class objects, as identified by a customer id, and set an offer variable within it.

My intial attempt fails because I've defined customer as a String, which is why customer.receiveTender(target) won't work. But I also tried Agent and the Customer subclass but they don't work.

I'm very new to Java - can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public class Trader extends Robot {

    private String target;

    public String selectTarget(String target) {
        target = target;
    }

    public void issueOffer(String target, String customer) {
        customer.receiveOffer(target);
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

```
public class Robot {

    private String id;  

    public Robot() {
        id = "No name yet";
    }

    public void setID (String newID) {
        id = newID;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

}

public class Customer extends Robot {

    private String target;

    public void receiveOffer(String target) {
        target = target;
    }

}
```

Comment: please share complete code

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Where is `receiveTender()` defined? What's the problem when you replace `String` with the correct class?

Comment: `target = target;` - This seems fishy. Maybe you meant `this.target = target;`?

Comment: There is also a compile-time error. Method `public String selectTarget(String target)` returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, `receiveTender()` is not a member of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

Below line of code means an object with name `customer`, which is `String` type has method `receiveTender` and takes argument as `String` i.e. `target`. But, if you look at the [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, it doesn't have any method with name `receiveTender` and that's the reason. It **won't** compile.

```
customer.receiveTender(target);
```

As per your updated code, `receiveOffer` is a member of `Customer` class, which means you need to have instance of `Customer` class to access its method and that means it should be

```
public void issueOffer(String target, Customer customer) {
    customer.receiveOffer(target);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvote.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Neil It might be because, (s)he wouldn't read complete post or s(he) may not likes my posts :-)

Comment: @Ravi, thanks for that. I've come from Python where it's a lot less strict. I appreciate your time. It now works. :)

Comment: @elksie5000 Np, I understand and I appreciate when people ask questions

Answer (score -1):

Majority of the times, one class can speak to another class only when the class has an object of another class. Inheritance come into picture for "is a" relationship. The Trader class written above will only make sense if Trader is a Robot otherwise create two separate classes as Robot and Trader.

Comment: Trader *is a* Robot in the example given.  Your solution is to make Trader derive from Robot or create two separate classes?  How does this solve the problem related to calling receiveTender on String customer?

Comment: Well when I answered the question, the questions was mainly on communication between two objects and was later updated. The person said he is very new to Java so I give a brief answer about how two objects can communicate with each other.

Comment: Well that doesn't change the fact that now this answer is unsuitable for the question.  Please update your answer or the downvote will remain on my part.